# QtQuick, QML and C++ integration: how to make public variables definied inside .h file visible in QML file?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, integration

After integration C++ and QML using the way described here:

[QML C++ integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knlH_NF8PAs&t=32s)

I have noticed only .h methods are visible outside class (from QML level), I have no access for public variables.
After research I found that:

```
void QQmlContext::setContextProperty(const QString &name, const QVariant &value)
```

Is this way proper?

If not, how can I get access to my class public variables from QML level ?

Supposedly I can create functions for this purpose, but I don't like this way.
It looks for me like way around...

Comment: How about https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html and https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html ?

Comment: Okay. I'm studying that right now. Is this enough to set these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example, I wanted to expose the C++ `qVersion()` from `QtGlobal` to QML as `System.qtVersion`.

```cpp
//System.h
#ifndef System_H
#define System_H
#include <QObject>
class System : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString qtVersion READ qtVersion CONSTANT)
public:
    System(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    QString qtVersion() const;
};
#endif
```

````
//System.cpp
#include "System.h"
System::System(QObject * parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}
QString System::qtVersion() const
{
    return qVersion();
}
#endif

```c++
//main.cpp
    //...
    qmlRegisterSingletonType<System>("qmlonline", 1, 0, "System", [](QQmlEngine*,QJSEngine*) -> QObject* { return new System(); } );
````

I can access the above in QML with the following snippet:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import qmlonline
Page {
    Text {
        text: System.qtVersion
    }
}
```

You can try the [QML portion online](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAAcXicy8wtyC8qUQgsCSzNTM7mykTh6jnn55UU5ecUw8QLc3Py83Iy81K5AhLTUxWquRSAICS1ogTKBIESINdKIbiyuCQ1V6+wJCy1qDgzPw8sXctVywUA29klRg==)

For other examples of C++ wrappings to QML checkout my GitHub projects:

- https://github.com/stephenquan/qt-toolkit
- https://github.com/stephenquan/qmlonline6

Comment: Thanks Stephen ! Nice done with QML portion online, I will cheeck this in future, since this time I am concentrated on QML and C++ integration. I didn't expect so many issues will appear. So each public variable needs read function? Isn't it possible from C++variable-acces-from-QML level?

Comment: Okay! Now my data appears in QML file !  I will answer my question above so: yes, variable needs read data function (without this it didn't work) Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use `READ read_function` or `MEMBER m_memberVariable`. The latter implements automatic/default readers/writers for your variable so you don't have to. But, in either case, a signal is recommended for property binding to function properly.